# How to migrate data from ES2.1 to ES7 by logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

> [ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Failed to install
> template {:message=>"Got response code '400' contacting Elasticsearch
> at URL 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_template/ecs-logstash'",
> :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError

original ES version: 2.1.2 new ES version: 7.13 logstash version: 8.1.1

I have below index on my ES2

```json
"designs_v1": {
        "mappings": {
            "design": {
                "dynamic": "false",
                "_all": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "_id": {
                    "store": true,
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "_timestamp": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "store": true
                },
                "properties": {
                    "createDate": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "fielddata": {
                            "__comment": "Used for sorting",
                            "loading": "eager"
                        },
                        "format": "epoch_millis||date_time"
                    },
                    "designId": {
                        "type": "long",
                        "fielddata": {
                            "__comment": "Used for sorting to break ties and accessed by our custom scorer",
                            "loading": "eager"
                        }
                    },
                    "editorialTags": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "norms": {
                            "loading": "eager"
                        },
                        "analyzer": "standard_with_stopwords",
                        "fields": {
                            "shingles": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "norms": {
                                    "loading": "eager"
                                },
                                "analyzer": "shingle"
                            },
                            "stemmed": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "norms": {
                                    "loading": "eager"
                                },
                                "analyzer": "kstem"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "isPersonalizable": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "legalBlockTags": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "norms": {
                            "enabled": false
                        },
                        "analyzer": "standard_with_stopwords"
                    },
                    "memberId": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "pixel_height": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "pixel_width": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "products": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "caption": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "norms": {
                                    "enabled": false
                                },
                                "analyzer": "standard_with_stopwords"
                            },
                            "createDate": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "format": "epoch_millis||date_time"
                            },
                            "defaultThumbnail": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "description": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "norms": {
                                    "enabled": false
                                },
                                "analyzer": "standard_with_stopwords"
                            },
                            "hasPersonalizableSvg": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "imageOneId": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "imageTwoId": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "locations": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "norms": {
                                    "enabled": false
                                },
                                "analyzer": "keyword"
                            },
                            "productId": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "productTypeId": {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "fielddata": {
                                    "__comment": "Used during aggregations",
                                    "loading": "eager"
                                }
                            },
                            "showColorId": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "storeId": {
                                "type": "long"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "sellerTags": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "norms": {
                            "loading": "eager"
                        },
                        "analyzer": "standard_with_stopwords",
                        "fields": {
                            "shingles": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "norms": {
                                    "loading": "eager"
                                },
                                "analyzer": "shingle"
                            },
                            "stemmed": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "norms": {
                                    "loading": "eager"
                                },
                                "analyzer": "kstem"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I created new index in ES7:

```json
{
"mappings": {
        // "_id": {
        //     "store": true,
        //     "index": "not_analyzed"
        // },
        // "_timestamp": {
        //     "enabled": true,
        //     "store": true
        // },
        "properties": {
            "createDate": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "epoch_millis||date_time"
            },
            "designId": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "editorialTags": {
                "type": "text",
                "norms": true,
                "analyzer": "standard_with_stopwords",
                "fields": {
                    "shingles": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "norms": true,
                        "analyzer": "shingle"
                    },
                    "stemmed": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "norms": true,
                        "analyzer": "kstem"
                    }
                }
            },
            "isPersonalizable": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "legalBlockTags": {
                "type": "text",
                "norms": false,
                "analyzer": "standard_with_stopwords"
            },
            "memberId": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "pixel_height": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "pixel_width": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "products": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "caption": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "norms": false,
                        "analyzer": "standard_with_stopwords"
                    },
                    "createDate": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "epoch_millis||date_time"
                    },
                    "defaultThumbnail": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "norms": false,
                        "analyzer": "standard_with_stopwords"
                    },
                    "hasPersonalizableSvg": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "imageOneId": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "imageTwoId": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "locations": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "norms": false,
                        "analyzer": "keyword"
                    },
                    "productId": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "productTypeId": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "showColorId": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "storeId": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            },
            "sellerTags": {
                "type": "text",
                "norms": true,
                "analyzer": "standard_with_stopwords",
                "fields": {
                    "shingles": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "norms": true,
                        "analyzer": "shingle"
                    },
                    "stemmed": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "norms": true,
                        "analyzer": "kstem"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to migrate data to ES7 by logstash, below is my logstash conf file:

```json
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://xxx:9200"]
    index => "designs_v1"
    type => "design"
    size => 10
    scroll => "1m"
  }
}
filter {
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"]
    index => "designs_v1"
    #document_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
}
```

But I can't fix issue:

> [ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Failed to install
> template {:message=>"Got response code '400' contacting Elasticsearch
> at URL 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_template/ecs-logstash'",
> :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError

What can I do now?

Comment: There are breaking changes from version 7 to version 8 and this impact on how logstash send data to Elasticsearch. You can't use Logstash 8.1.1 with Elasticsearch 7.13, the [maximum](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_compatibility) Logstash version you can use with this Elasticsearch version is the 7.17. Try to use the same version for Logstash and Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed this issue by the same solution